# Transform Rotate Image Positioning Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, transform

I'm having problems moving around an image which i previously rotated with *transform rotate*.

More specifically, when the image is rotated the top and left attributes are not updated, so it seems as the image is rotated only graphically.

What I'd like to do is be able to move the image freely after I rotate it, but it is really imprecise.

This is the image class

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    width:20%;
}
```

And this is the rotation code

```
degree = $("#angleSlider").val();
$(ele).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="element" src="img.png">
  <img class="element" src="img1.png">
  <img class="element" src="img2.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Put the image inside a container, move the container instead.

Comment: can you post some html alsto to better understand your problem?

Comment: *"so it seems as the image is rotated only graphically."* - Yep that's **precisely** what `transform` does.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Transform does not change top left property value.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');

document.getElementById('degree').addEventListener('input', function() {
  img.style.transform = "rotate(" + this.value + "deg)";
});

document.getElementById('top').addEventListener('input', function() {
  img.style.top = this.value + "px";
});

document.getElementById('left').addEventListener('input', function() {
  img.style.left = this.value + "%";
});
```

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  height: 200px;
  
}

.img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x4:3/" id="img" />
</div>
<div>
  Rotate:
  <input type="range" id="degree" min="0" max="360" step="any" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
  Top:
  <input type="range" id="top" min="0" max="88" step="any" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
  Left:
  <input type="range" id="left" min="0" max="100" step="any" value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's a nice demo @Miraz

Comment: Thank you for appreciation @bhansa.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it also depends on what browser you are using.

```
$(ele).css({"-moz-transform":"rotate(" + degree + "deg)"});
$(ele).css({"-ms-transform":"rotate(" + degree + "deg)"});
$(ele).css({"-webkit-transform":"rotate(" + degree + "deg)"});
$(ele).css({"transform":"rotate(" + degree + "deg)"});
```

Comment: I've already implemented the cross-browser compatiblity, that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example using the slider, although `transform` will rotate the element graphically that's true.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var degree;
  $(document).on("input", "#myRange", function(){
  degree = $(this).val();
  $(".element").css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
});
});
```

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  top:30%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width:20%;
}

#angleslider{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="angleslider">
 <span>0 deg</span> <input type="range" min="1" max="350" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange"><span> 360 deg </span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img class="element" src="http://img.freepik.com/free-icon/move-to-next_318-80203.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding a container to each image I had, moving all the properties to the div and make the `transform-rotate` only on the image

Comment: Check the below answer of mine, I havent used container for each image, but you can use id's to target them specifically.